# How to use Django template context processor and form together?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am a newbie to Django. In a project I have to take inputs for multiple models in Django using forms.
For every model I have written functions (in views.py) and its corresponding Django template (in template folder).
Such as,my Add Teacher function is,

```
def add_teacher(request):
    form = TeacherForm()

    if request.method=="POST":
        form = TeacherForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)

            return index(request)
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    return  render(request,"billing/add_teacher.html",{"form":form})
```

And billing/add_teacher.html template is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Teacher</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add a Discipline</h1>
    <div>
        <form id="teacher_form" method="post" action="/billing/add_teacher/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Teacher"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to use a template for all of my functions.Such as, I want to use this template for all functions with the help of Django template context processor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ h1 }}</h1>
    <div>
        <form id={{ form_id }} method="post" action="{{ action }}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.help_text }}
            {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value={{ value }}/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I return render() function I only can set either context or form.Such as, I can use one of these,

```
return  render(request,"billing/add_teacher.html",{"form":form})
```

or,

```
return  render(request,"billing/add_teacher.html",context= context_dict)
```

How can I use both of these together?
Something like,

```
return  render(request,"billing/add_teacher.html",{"form":form},context =context_dict)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
context_dict.update({"form":form})
return  render(request, "billing/add_teacher.html", context=context_dict)
```

Comment: Any specific reason you choose to use the `update` method over `context_dict['form'] = form`?

Comment: The `context` is just a dictionary with values that you want to tell the template about. So you build a dictionary and pass it in. The code above just adds `"form"` to all the things `context_dict` already contains.